# How to call a function from stateless Widget that points to state class function?

Tags: flutter, oop

I am trying to create a responsive chatbot with quick replies. I want to make a button on pressed function call to another class's function. I tried using the callback. But i think i am doing something wrong. Kindly help me.

```
typedef void mycallback(String label);

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();
  late DialogFlowtter dialogFlowtter;
  final TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DialogFlowtter.fromFile().then((instance) => dialogFlowtter = instance);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var themeValue = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    Body(
      hi: sendMessage,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: themeValue == Brightness.dark
          ? HexColor('#262626')
          : HexColor('#FFFFFF'),
      appBar: AppBar(
        //app bar ui
        ),
        actions: [
          //list if widget in appbar actions
          PopupMenuButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu), 
            color: Colors.blue,
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem<int>(
                value: 0,
                child: Text(
                  "Log out",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            onSelected: (item) => {logout(context)},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Body(messages: messages)),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 10,
                vertical: 5,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: messageController,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: themeValue == Brightness.dark
                              ? Colors.white
                              : Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                color: themeValue == Brightness.dark
                                    ? Colors.white
                                    : Colors.black),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: themeValue == Brightness.dark
                              ? Colors.white54
                              : Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        ),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: themeValue == Brightness.dark
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.black),
                        hintText: "Type here...",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    color: themeValue == Brightness.dark
                        ? Colors.white
                        : Colors.black,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                    onPressed: () {
                      sendMessage(messageController.text);
                      messageController.clear();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void sendMessage(String text) async {
    if (text.isEmpty) return;
    setState(() {
     //do main function
    });
     }
 
}
```

The class from where i want to call the function

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages;
  final mycallback? hi;
  const Body({
    Key? key,
    this.messages = const [],
    this.buttons = const [],
    this.hi,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        var obj = messages[messages.length - 1 - i];
        Message message = obj['message'];
        bool isUserMessage = obj['isUserMessage'] ?? false;
        String label = obj['label'];
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment:
              isUserMessage ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            _MessageContainer(
              message: message,
              isUserMessage: isUserMessage,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(label),
              onPressed: () => {hi ?? (label)},//This is where i want to call
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.blueAccent,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (_, i) => Container(height: 10),
      itemCount: messages.length,
      reverse: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 10,
        vertical: 20,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code runs without errors but nothing happens when i press the buttons.

Comment: I am not sure what you wanted to do with this "hi ?? (label)", but to execute function you give to hi variable you need to add (). So hi() would execute it

Comment: I tried to call hi() but it throws null check operator exception

Comment: Thank you! I found the error. i didn't initialize it in class one properly! after doing that hi() didn't threw any exception!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.
In the class HomeScreen, I missed this line.

```
 child: Body(
              messages: messages,
              hi: (text) => {sendMessage(text)}, //this line
            )
```

After adding this line, the callback worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd implement something like that. You're basically asking for a void as parameter inside your widget. Almost like a TextButton or another widget like that.

You can use this with two stateful widets as well, since you're borrowing the function from one to another.

Also I think this would be done better with provider so I suggest you look into it. (I don't have enough experience with it)
https://pub.dev/packages/provider

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int x = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('An app'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('$x'),
            TestWidget(onTap: () {
              setState(() {
             x++;
             });
              
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  const TestWidget({Key? key, required this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('test')),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But can we implement async in widget function?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make it an async function. TestWidget(onTap: () async{})

Comment: Thank you! but i found the error. The initialization in class one has not been done properly.